# Brush extent/width on dropdown change (dc.js,moment.js,d3.js ,crossfilter)

Tags: momentjs, dc.js

**I have to create a brush with fixed extent values coming from a drop-down** ( 3,6,12,24 hours).Trying to get the affect of the brush as the brush extent here http://jsfiddle.net/9yccpjbu/, but instead of buttons to use the drop-down (like here http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/400wd2nd/16/).
A fix to the buttons is welcomed as well.

**Dropdown**

1) **The drop-down changes the displayed stack (the bars: g.chart-body- g.stack) only on the first click**,to  display the proper value coming from the drop-down:

[image]

When clicking on another value from the drop down it adds the value in white without rendering the stack (in the picture the result of selecting 6 from the drop-down(gray bars) and than 3(white):

[image]

2) **After clicking, the drop-down brush-extent (rect.extent) is diconnected from

   the g.chart-body- g.stack**. (red border in the picture):

[image].

Without the drop-down being clicked, selecting the brush from the timeSlider works good and looks like this:

[image]

3) **After clicking the drop-down the number of selected records shown in "Reset All" link is 0** (moving rect.extent on the stack shows the number of selected records).

4) **"Reset All" link does not reset** the graphs** and shows the number of items selected by the dropdown

**The buttons:**

4) When clicked they show the expected drawing of the g.chart-body- g.stack and the complementary rect.extent on the dimension (stack+rect.extent= dimesion):

[image]

When I change the range from

```
filterDimension.filterRange([start, start.add('hours,amountHours).hours()])
```

to

```
filterDimension.filterRange([start.add('hours', amountHours).hours(), end])
```

The g.chart-body- g.stack and the rect.extent are joined - but on the complementary range of the range which I need to show the brush extent coming from the dropdown (my needed range (gray) + range shown (blue with red border) = domain):

[image]

5) The "Reset All" link seems to reset the graphs but shows wrong numbers when the "Reset all" is clicked.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dani2011/upa3eowb/

JAVASCRIPT

```
            'use strict';
            // chart objects 
            var bitChart = dc.compositeChart("#bitrate-move-chart");//Before dynamic Y-Axis nonzero_min used var bitChart = dc.lineChart('#bitrate-move-chart');
            var bitChart2 = dc.compositeChart("#bitrate-move-chart2");//Before dynamic Y-Axis nonzero_min used var bitChart = dc.lineChart('#bitrate-move-chart');
            var timeSlider = dc.barChart('#bitrate-timeSlider-chart');
            var bitCount = dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count');
            var bitrateTable = dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table');

            //Creating dynamic Y axis with min/max ticks' values depending on min/max of data - copied from http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/7anae5c5/1/...

            // 15 Min Interval - copied from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/time/interval.js.....

            // generalization of d3.time.minute copied from- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/time/minute.js....

            //bitchart
            var min15 = n_minutes_interval(15);
            //bitchart_2
            var min15_2 = n_minutes_interval(15);
            //timeSlider
            var min15_3 = n_minutes_interval(15);

            //### Load  data 
            //var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("pre#data").text());
            d3.csv('CHANNEL_CLUSTER_BITRATE_takeThis.csv', function (data) {
                // Format CSV data
                var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M');
                var numberFormat = d3.format('.2');
                data.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.bitdate = new Date(d.DATETIME);    //d.DATETIME = dateFormat.parse(d.DATETIME);
                    d.hours = d3.time.hours(d.bitdate);
                    d.BITRATE = +d.BITRATE.match(/\d+/); //d.BITRATE = +d.BITRATE; 
                });

                //### Crossfilter Dimensions 
                var crossFilteredData = crossfilter(data);
                var all = crossFilteredData.groupAll();
                // Dimension by full date
                //bitChart
                var dateDimension = crossFilteredData.dimension(function (d) {
                    return d.bitdate;
                });
                //bitChart2
                var dateDimension2 = crossFilteredData.dimension(function (d) {
                    return d.bitdate;
                });
                //timeSlider
                var dateDimension3 = crossFilteredData.dimension(function (d) {
                    return d.bitdate;
                });
                //dropDown
                var filterDimension = crossFilteredData.dimension(function (d) {
                    return d.bitdate;
                });

                //### Crossfiltered Groups
                //timeSlider
                var minIntervalWeekBitrateGroup3 = dateDimension3.group(min15_3).reduceSum(function (d) {
                    return 10 //  +d.BITRATE
                });

                //Group bitrate per week, 15 minInterval - maintain running tallies 
                //bitChart
                var bitrateWeekMinIntervalGroupMove = dateDimension.group(min15).reduce(
                   /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
                   function (p, v) {
                       ++p.count;
                       p.BITRATE = +v.BITRATE;
                       p.total += +v.BITRATE;
                       p.avg = p.count ? Math.round(p.total / p.count) : 0;
                       return p;
                   },
                   /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
                   function (p, v) {
                       --p.count;
                       p.BITRATE = +v.BITRATE;
                       p.total -= +v.BITRATE;
                       p.avg = p.count ? Math.round(p.total / p.count) : 0;
                       return p;
                   },
                   /* initialize p */
                   function () {
                       return {
                           count: 0,
                           bitrate: 0,
                           total: 0,
                           avg: 0
                       };
                   }
                );

                //bitChart2
                var bitrateWeekMinIntervalGroupMove2 = dateDimension2.group(min15_2).reduce(
                  /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
                  function (p, v) {
                      ++p.count;
                      p.BITRATE = +v.BITRATE;
                      p.total += +v.BITRATE;
                      p.avg = p.count ? Math.round(p.total / p.count) : 0;
                      return p;
                  },
                  /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
                  function (p, v) {
                      --p.count;
                      p.BITRATE = +v.BITRATE;
                      p.total -= +v.BITRATE;
                      p.avg = p.count ? Math.round(p.total / p.count) : 0;
                      return p;
                  },
                  /* initialize p */
                  function () {
                      return {
                          count: 0,
                          bitrate: 0,
                          total: 0,
                          avg: 0
                      };
                  }
               );

                //domain limits
                var minDate = dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].DATETIME;
                var maxDate = dateDimension.top(1)[0].DATETIME;
                var start = moment(new Date(minDate));
                var end = moment(new Date(maxDate)); 
                //max line
                var maxbit = d3.max(data, function (d) { return  
                +d["BITRATE"]; }); 

                //dropdown / buttons copied from http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/400wd2nd/16/ , http://jsfiddle.net/9yccpjbu/
                var btns = d3.select(".buttons-container").selectAll("button").data(["3 Hours", "6 Hours", "12 Hours", "24 Hours"]);
                    btns = btns.enter().append("button")
                   .attr("class", "btn btn-sm btn-success")
                    // fill the buttons with the year from the data assigned to them
                    btns.each(function (d) {
                        this.innerText = d;
                    })
                    btns.on("click", drawBrush)

              function drawBrush() {
                    if (this.innerText === "Brush Extent") {  }
                    if (this.innerText === "3 Hours") { addHours(3);  }
                    if (this.innerText === "6 Hours") { addHours(6); }
                    if (this.innerText === "12 Hours") { addHours(12); }
                    if (this.innerText === "24 Hours") { addHours(24); }
                    timeSlider.filter(null);
                    timeSlider.filter(dc.filters.RangedFilter( start, end);
                   // timeSlider.x.domain(brush.empty() ? 
                    timeSlider.x.domain() : brush.extent());
                    dc.redrawAll();
              }

                function addHours(amountHours) {

                    filterDimension.filterRange([start, start.add('hours', amountHours).hours()]);
                    //filterDimension.filterRange([start.add('hours', amountHours).hours(), end]);
                    dc.redrawAll();
                }

                function brushed() {
                    timeSlider.x.domain(brush.empty()) ?    
                    timeSlider.x.domain() : brush.extent());
                }
                function fixed_now() {
                    return new Date(minDate)
                }

                d3.select('#hoursDropDown').on('change', function() {
                   filterDimension.filterRange([start, start.add(this.value,  
                   'hours').hours()]);
                    dc.redrawAll();
                    timeSlider.filter(null);//filterAll()
                    timeSlider.filter(dc.filters.RangedFilter(new 
                    Date(start), new Date(end)));
                    dc.redrawAll();

                  //  timeSlider.x.domain(brush.empty() ? 
                  //  timeSlider.x.domain() : brush.extent());

                    //var start = moment(new Date(minDate));
                   // var end = moment(new Date(maxDate));
                   // filterDimension.filterRange([start,  
                   //start.add(this.value, 'hours').hours()]);
                  //  dc.redrawAll();

                });

                //###Graphs
                bitChart /* dc.lineChart('#bitrate-move-chart', 'chartGroup') */
                    .xUnits(min15.range)  //.xUnits(d3.time.weeks)//.round(d3.time.week) //.round(d3.time.minute)//d3.time.month.round)
                    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(minDate), new Date(maxDate)]))
                    .yAxisPadding('5%')     
                    .elasticY(true)
                   //Specify a "range chart" to link its brush extent with the zoom of the current "focus chart".
                    .rangeChart(timeSlider)
                    .width(450)
                    .height(200)
                    .transitionDuration(500)
                    .margins({ top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 50, padding: 1 })
                    .mouseZoomable(true)
                    .brushOn(false)
                    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                    .legend(dc.legend().x(800).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
                    //Render max bitrate horizontal line copied from bar-extra-line.html
                     .yAxisLabel("Total Bitrate per 15 minutes")
                    .renderlet(function (chart) {
                        chart.svg().selectAll('.chart-body').attr('clip-path', null)
                    })
                    .on('renderlet', function (chart) {
                        var left_y = 10, right_y = 70; // use real statistics here!
                        var extra_data = [{ x: chart.x().range()[0], y: chart.y()(left_y) }, { x: chart.x().range()[1], y: chart.y()(right_y) }];
                        var line = d3.svg.line()
                            .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                            .y(function (d) { return maxbit; })
                            .interpolate('linear');
                        var chartBody = chart.select('g.chart-body');
                        var path = chartBody.selectAll('path.extra').data([extra_data]);
                        path.enter().append('path').attr({
                            class: 'extra',
                            stroke: 'red',
                            id: 'extra-line'
                        });
                        path.attr('d', line);
                        // Label the max line
                        var text = chartBody.selectAll('text.extra-label').data([0]);
                        text.enter().append('text')
                                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                            .append('textPath').attr({
                                class: 'extra-label',
                                'xlink:href': '#extra-line',
                                startOffset: '50%'
                            })
                            .text('Total Bitrate Max Value');      
                    })
                    // .ordinalColors('red')
                   // Title can be called by any stack layer.
                    .title(function (d) {
                        var value = d.value.total ? d.value.total : d.value;
                        if (isNaN(value)) {
                            value = 0;
                        }
                        return dateFormat(d.key) + ' \n Total Bit:' + numberFormat(value)
                    })

                  //Creating dynamic Y axis with min max ticks' values depending on min max of data - copied from http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/7anae5c5/1/
                 .compose([
                  nonzero_min(dc.lineChart(bitChart)
                      .dimension(min15)
                       .colors('blue')
                       .group(bitrateWeekMinIntervalGroupMove, 'Bitrate Total')

                       .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                            return d.value.total;
                        })
                     // .dashStyle([2,2])
                     .interpolate('step-after')
                      .renderArea(false)
                      .brushOn(false)
                      .renderDataPoints(false)         
                      .clipPadding(10)),
                 ])
                bitChart.render();

                //bitchart2
                bitChart2 /* dc.lineChart('#bitrate-move-chart', 'chartGroup') */
                   .xUnits(min15_2.range)  //.xUnits(d3.time.weeks)//.round(d3.time.week) //.round(d3.time.minute)//d3.time.month.round)
                   .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(minDate), new Date(maxDate)]))
                   .yAxisPadding('5%')
                   .elasticY(true)
                  //Specify a "range chart" to link its brush extent with the zoom of the current "focus chart".
                   .rangeChart(timeSlider)
                   .width(450)
                   .height(200)
                   .transitionDuration(500)
                   .margins({ top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 50, padding: 1 })
                   .mouseZoomable(true)
                   .brushOn(false)
                   .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                   .legend(dc.legend().x(800).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
                   //Render max bitrate horizontal line copied from bar-extra-line.html
                    .yAxisLabel("Total Bitrate per 15 minutes")
                   .renderlet(function (chart) {
                       chart.svg().selectAll('.chart-body').attr('clip-path', null)
                   })
                   .on('renderlet', function (chart) {
                       var left_y = 10, right_y = 70; // use real statistics here!
                       var extra_data = [{ x: chart.x().range()[0], y: chart.y()(left_y) }, { x: chart.x().range()[1], y: chart.y()(right_y) }];
                       var line = d3.svg.line()
                           .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                           .y(function (d) { return maxbit; })
                           .interpolate('linear');
                       var chartBody = chart.select('g.chart-body');
                       var path = chartBody.selectAll('path.extra').data([extra_data]);
                       path.enter().append('path').attr({
                           class: 'extra',
                           stroke: 'red',
                           id: 'extra-line'
                       });
                       path.attr('d', line);
                       // Label the max line
                       var text = chartBody.selectAll('text.extra-label').data([0]);
                       text.enter().append('text')
                       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                       .append('textPath').attr({
                               class: 'extra-label',
                               'xlink:href': '#extra-line',
                               startOffset: '50%'
                           })
                           .text('Total Bitrate Max Value');
                   })
                   // .ordinalColors('red')
                  // Title can be called by any stack layer.
                   .title(function (d) {
                       var value = d.value.total ? d.value.total : d.value;
                       if (isNaN(value)) {
                           value = 0;
                       }
                       return dateFormat(d.key) + ' \n Total Bit:' + numberFormat(value)
                   })

                 //Creating dynamic Y axis with min max ticks' values depending on min max of data - copied from http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/7anae5c5/1/
                .compose([
                 nonzero_min(dc.lineChart(bitChart2)
                     .dimension(min15_2)
                      .colors('blue')
                      .group(bitrateWeekMinIntervalGroupMove2, 'Bitrate Total')
                      .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                          return d.value.total;
                      })
                     //.dashStyle([2,2])
                    .interpolate('step-after')
                     .renderArea(false)
                     .brushOn(false)
                     .renderDataPoints(false)
                     .clipPadding(10)),
                ])
                bitChart2.render();

                //#### Range Chart
                // Since this bar chart is specified as "range chart" for the area chart, its brush extent will always match the zoom of the area chart.
                timeSlider
                   .dimension(dateDimension3)//.dimension(min15)//.dimension(weekDim)//   //
                    .group(minIntervalWeekBitrateGroup3)
                    // .x(d3.time.scale().range([0, brushContainer.select("rect").attr("width")]).domain([new Date(dateDimension3.bottom(1)[0].DATETIME), new Date(dateDimension3.top(1)[0].DATETIME)]))
                    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(dateDimension3.bottom(1)[0].DATETIME), new Date(dateDimension3.top(1)[0].DATETIME)]))
                    .round(dc.round.floor) //(d3.time.month.round)
                    .xUnits(min15_3.range)//.xUnits(d3.time.week) //.xUnits(d3.time.minute) //.xUnits(d3.time.months)
                    .width(990) /* dc.barChart('#bitrate-timeSlider-chart', 'chartGroup'); */
                    .height(40)
                    .margins({ top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 40 })
                   // .centerBar(true)
                    .gap(1)
                    .mouseZoomable(true)
                //#### Data Count  dateformat.parse(d.time);
                bitCount /* dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count', 'chartGroup'); */
                    .dimension(crossFilteredData)
                    .group(all)
                    .html({
                        some: '<strong>%filter-count</strong> records selected out of <strong>%total-count</strong> records'  +
                            ' | <a href=\'javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();\'>Reset All</a>',
                        all: ' All records selected. Please click on the graph to apply filters.'
                    });
                //#### Data Table
                bitrateTable /* dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table', 'chartGroup') */
                    .dimension(dateDimension)    //  .dimension(dateDimension)
                    // Data table does not use crossfilter group but rather a closure as a grouping function
                    .group(function (d) {
                        var format = d3.format('02d');
                        return d.bitdate.getFullYear() + '/' + format((d.bitdate.getMonth() + 1));
                    })
                    .sortBy(function (d) { return d.bitdate; })
                    // (_optional_) max number of records to be shown, `default = 25`
                    .size(13)
                    .columns([
                        'DATETIME',
                        'CHANNEL_ID',
                        'BITRATE'
                    ])
                    // (_optional_) custom renderlet to post-process chart using [D3](http://d3js.org)
                    .on('renderlet', function (table) {
                        table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
                    });
                //#### Rendering
                //Render all charts on the page
                dc.renderAll();


                //#### Versions
                //Determine the current version of dc with `dc.version`
                d3.selectAll('#version').text(dc.version);
                // Determine latest stable version in the repo via Github API
                d3.json('https://api.github.com/repos/dc-js/dc.js/releases/latest', function (error, latestRelease) {
                    /*jshint camelcase: false */
                    d3.selectAll('#latest').text(latestRelease.tag_name); /* jscs:disable */
                });

            });

            //d3.select('#myDropDown2').on('change', function () {
            //    var nd = new Date(minDate);
            //    nd.setDate(nd.getDate() + +this.value);
            // var start1 = moment(new Date(d.key));
            //var nd = new Date(minDate);
            //nd.setDate(nd.getDate());
            //    filterDimension.filterRange([nd, nd.setDate(nd.getDate() + +this.value)]);
            //    dc.redrawAll();
            //});

            //var brushContainer = d3.select("svg");
            //alert( brushContainer.select("rect").attr("width"));
            // start.max(new Date(minDate), new Date(maxDate));
            // moment.max(start, end);
            //if ((start.add(this.value, 'hours').hours()).getTime()>= end)
            //{
            //    filterDimension.filterRange([start, end]);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //filterDimension.filterRange([start, start.add(this.value, 'hours').hours()]);
            //}
            // timeSlider.filter(null);
            //d3.select("svg").select("rect").enter().append('rect').attr({  width: ''+ this.value +''  });
            //  timeSlider.x.domain(brush.empty() ? timeSlider.x.domain() : brush.extent(0,this.value));
            //  focus.select("timeSlider.area").attr("d", area);
            // focus.select("timeSlider.x.axis").call(xAxis);
            // }

            // dc.renderAll();
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Tried also to add and change the following lines of code (didn't work either):             brush.extent([new Date(start), new Date( end)]);
                        brush(timeSlider.select(".brush").transition().delay(1000));
                        dateDimension3 = data.filter(function (d, i) {
                        var mon2 = moment(new Date(d.bitdate)).format("YYYY-         MM-DD");
                            if ((mon2 >= start) && (mon2 <= end)) {
                                return d.bitdate;
                            }...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of excess code here. If something doesn't work, you should really remove it before trying the next thing. :)

So, this is really quite simple.

First, you should usually set the filter through the chart, not directly on the crossfilter dimension. Crossfilter doesn't provide any getters, so the charts need to be told where to show the brush. And a separate `filterDimension` would only be needed if there is no chart showing the time filter. Setting this extra dimension meant that when the chart got reset, there is still extra filtering happening, so the reset doesn't take.

To make the buttons work the same as the drop-down, let's just use `addHours` for both. We can also use `replaceFilter`, which should be a little bit quicker than doing `.filter(null)` and then setting another filter:

```
function drawBrush() {
    if (this.innerText === "Brush Extent") {  }
    if (this.innerText === "3 Hours") { addHours(3);  }
    if (this.innerText === "6 Hours") { addHours(6); }
    if (this.innerText === "12 Hours") { addHours(12); }
    if (this.innerText === "24 Hours") { addHours(24); }
}

d3.select('#hoursDropDown').on('change', function() {
    addHours(this.value);
});

function addHours(amountHours) {
    timeSlider.replaceFilter(...);
    dc.redrawAll();
}
```

Now what goes in `...`? I think this was the other part that was making this so confusing, and it took me a while to figure it out. You might expect that moment.js uses a functional style where it has no side effects, but in fact, it's modifying the date object every time. So if you call

```
start.add(amountHours, 'hours')
```

multiple times, it keeps adding more hours to `start` every time! Instead, we can [clone `start` before modifying it](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/):

```
moment(start).add(amountHours, 'hours')
```

(Note: I've also reversed the order of the arguments, because moment was complaining about a deprecated interface.)

Another problem here is that you don't want to call `moment.hours()` - that will fetch just the hours, an integer and not a valid date object anymore.

Putting this all together, it's just:

```
function addHours(amountHours) {
    timeSlider.replaceFilter(dc.filters.RangedFilter(start, moment(start).add(amountHours, 'hours')));
    dc.redrawAll();
}
```

Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ewmrmu83/9/

Comment: Big Thank You Gordon - for all your time,help and explanations. Was not aware of the cloning while using moment.js and not of replaceFilter functionality.Appreciate this very much - Dani.